# `adb push` files are not showing on Android 11 Emulator

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to copy photos onto my Android Emulator. I have tried

- dragging photos onto the device screen (copying files popup does show up), but the photos do not appear anywhere. This **worked** on Android 8.1 and 10.
- tried adb-pushing photos onto an Android 11 emulator. Although adb-pushed files are present on the file system (on both `/sdcard/DCIM` and `/sdcard/Pictures`), they do not show up on the device. I used `adb push * /sdcard/DCIM`, in a local directory with 24 photos.
- I have also tried restarting the emulator (using the restart button on the Android UI), and no images were found. These images still exist on the filesystem. (This rules out me starting an older snapshot)

Unfortunately, the **Files** app shows these folders to be empty, even after restarting the emulator (Android UI restart button). My method working previously, but for some reason, can't copy photos onto the device now. Does anyone have a better method, or can confirm this method works for them?

---

Running Android Studio 4.1 (and tried 4.2 Canary) & Android 11.

Comment: You can do it with the Device Explorer of Android Studio.

Comment: `they do not show up on the device. ` Maybe. But that depends on the used app or code.

Comment: I think this is a bug with Android 11, considering Android 10 works fine for all the same apps (I used Google Photos and Files)

Comment: And with what did you check that they were present? Reboot the emulator and you will see them.

Comment: `You can do it with the Device Explorer of Android Studio.` The files are already present according to the File Explorer, as I successfully found them with `adb shell` anyway. The trouble is app *having access to these files*.

Comment: Which apps do not have access? I copied some files to DCIM with Device Explorer and they are visible to an app of mine. So i think they are visible to all apps then. They are visible in the Files app also. But not under Images but browsing primary storage. Android 11 emulator.

Comment: All apps (I wasn't able to find any app that can find the photos on the device.)

Comment: blackapps, when you say browsing primary storage, what app are you using, Files? Are you sure you're using API level 30 emulator, or API level 29 (Android 10)

Comment: Yes as i said using the Files app. Google Photos will not show them but that is the same as when Files app does not show them under Images. Just take a normal file explorer app and you will see them too.

Comment: Okay, for some reason, after a while, the photos showed up... Thanks for your help

Comment: It is all the problem scanned by MediaStore or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2 people have upvoted, I wanted to let you know how I work around this. **After pushing the files to the device, I always restart it**, and wait a couple of the minutes. This allows the MediaStore (which also handles stuff I would say is non-media, e.g. documents) to find the new pictures and add it to its own database.

Comment: Thanks it worked using 
    .\adb reboot